# Getting grid.column property of a control in a general styled event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

i have a lot of text boxes in my app, and a style which sets the event handler:

```
<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="GeneralTextBoxMouseEnter"/>
```

Text Boxes are Located in Grids so for example this is the xaml code for one of the text boxes:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="sat6" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource anHourSatAm}" />
</Grid>
```

this is the GeneralTextBoxMouseEnter event handler

```
    private void GeneralTextBoxMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        MessageBox.Show((String)(tb.Grid.Column);

    }
```

i get an error that such a property doesn't exist. but in properties box of VS2010 it exists, how can i retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use static method named GetColumn of Grid.

```
private void GeneralTextBoxMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        MessageBox.Show(Grid.GetColumn(tb));

    }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: with `MessageBox.Show(Grid.GetColumn(tb).ToString());` it works like a charm. thank you!